# Removing “Other User” from startup screen

Tags: macos, user-account

How do I get rid of "other user". I had used a Mac Tech prior and he worked on my Mac. It only showed my icon on the start up screen. Now I have another icon for another user which when I open it, it opens up a dark gray screen for what I believe is for screen sharing.

I would like to remove it and bring it back to just one user for the start up. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just deleting the user in System Preferences -> Users & Groups?

Comment: Does it say "Guest" or is it a different username?  Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a recent version of MacOS X.

In System Preferences, you need the Users & Groups panel.  **Click the padlock to allow making changes.**  You can then select the unwanted user account(s) and delete them from the list.

There's also a Guest User account.  To disable this, select it in the list of users, then untick "Allow guests to log in to this computer".

Comment: Is it different in older versions of macOS?

Comment: If you go back far enough, it could be.  I based the above instructions on the latest version.

Comment: Yes it's an early 2009 iMac running OX El Capitan version 10.11.6